# Can I limit a ManyToOne Self Join to only retrieve 1 result using hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, parent-child, limit

Im developing a catalog. Each Category can have a parent Category, resulting in a tree of infinite depth. Each time I retrieve an instance of Category I get the whole branch it comes from. Is there anyway that hibernate would only retrieve the direct parent of my category? here is my Category Class.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Category") 
public class Category { 
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name = "Id") private int id
private int id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 50)
@Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="Id_Parent")
private Category parent;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name = "parent")
private Set<Category> children;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Category getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Category parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public Set<Category> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(Set<Category> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
```

}

Comment: This might be interesting for you: [Models for hierarchical data](http://slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

Comment: The association is lazy, so Hibernate shouldn't retrieve any parent category. Note that cascade=ALL on a ManyToOne doesn't make much sense: deleting a child category would delete its parent, which would (hopefully) cause a foreign key constraint violation.

Comment: mmm I though it wouldnt retrieve the parent but it does all the way back to the root of the tree..thanks for the note on the cascade, you are right. Im new at this.

Comment: I highly doubt that. Post a minimal test case loading a category, enable SQL logging in the Hibernate configuration, and post the SQL query being executed.